# Comparing two dataframe from history checking in Apache Spark using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have adataframe with following structure

EmployeeDF

```
    id name  date       code
    1 John   2015-4-14  C11
    2 Roy    2011-5-20  C11
    3 John   2010-5-20  C11
    4 John   2012-5-20  C10
```

No i want to check history that if same code is apply to same employee two year ago. How can i do that. It is only sample data i have million of data in the dataframe and i want to achieve performance. Joining the dataframe slow down the performance because row are repeated so i make Cartesian and duplicate the rows during self join. I want to achieve with something like map.

> EDIT: The current code (adding from OP's comments.)

In the first step I am getting those employee who are repeated more than once because we are checking history and if some employee exist only once it means there is no history for this employee. So code for this step is:

```
val uniqueEmpDF = SparkConfig
  .sc
  .sqlContext
  .sql("SELECT *, '1' as level FROM cpeFirstStep WHERE e_id IN( SELECT e_id FROM cpeFirstStep where code = 'C11' " + " GROUP BY e_id HAVING COUNT(e_id)=1)")
  .cache()
```

Second step is to get the employee who are repeated and code is this:

```
val repeatedEmpDF = SparkConfig
  .sc
  .sqlContext
  .sql("SELECT *, '2' as level FROM cpeFirstStep WHERE e_id IN( SELECT e_id FROM cpeFirstStep where code = 'C11' " + " GROUP BY e_id HAVING COUNT(e_id)>1)")
  .cache()
```

Now the main step is following:

```
val historyJoin = SparkConfig
  .sc
  .sql("SELECT x.*, CASE WHEN y.code = x.code THEN '3' ELSE '4' END level FROM repeatedEmptDF X " + "LEFT JOIN repeatedEmptDF Y ON y.e_id = x.e_id AND y.code = x.code " + "AND y.date < x.data - INTERVAL 2 YEAR")
```

Comment: Exactly 2 years ago? What is the meaning of 2 years ago ? You can group on `"code" and "id"` then check the condition on dates.

Comment: Please provide the code you have written. It will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @ Sarvesh Kumar Singh I want to check history of each employee and if same code apply on same employee two or more year ago then mark this row to level 1 and in all other cases mark this row as level 2.

Comment: @Glennie Helles Sindholt Currently i have tried it with sql queries but it is taking lot of time. I want to do that with dataframe api with function like map etc.

Comment: Yes, but please post the code you have tried. Whether the code is working or very slow is not important, it will still help clue us into how you are thinking and identify where your chain of thought might need to be adjusted. People here at SO are much more inclined to help you, if you show a general interest in _learning_ and few will be willing to help if it's apparent that you just want someone to write the code for you.

Comment: In the first step i am getting those employee who are repeated more than once because we are checking history and if some employee exist only once it means there is no history for this employee. So code for this step is

           val uniqueEmpDF = SparkConfig.sc.sqlContext.sql("SELECT *, '1' as level FROM cpeFirstStep WHERE e_id IN( SELECT e_id FROM cpeFirstStep where code = 'C11' " +
        " GROUP BY e_id HAVING COUNT(e_id)=1)").cache();

Comment: Second step is to get the employee who are repeated and code is this

val repeatedEmpDF = SparkConfig.sc.sqlContext.sql("SELECT *, '2' as level FROM cpeFirstStep WHERE e_id IN( SELECT e_id FROM cpeFirstStep where code = 'C11' " +
        " GROUP BY e_id HAVING COUNT(e_id)>1)").cache();

Comment: Now the main step is following
  val historyJoin = SparkConfig.sc.sql("SELECT x.*, CASE WHEN y.code = x.code THEN '3' ELSE '4' END level  FROM repeatedEmptDF X " +
        "LEFT  JOIN repeatedEmptDF Y  ON y.e_id = x.e_id AND y.code = x.code " +
        "AND y.date < x.data - INTERVAL 2 YEAR");

Comment: @Glennie Helles Sindholt  e_id is employee id and this is also present in the table. If you dont understand let me know i will post full steps.

Comment: @Glennie Helles Sindholt I have very large dataset and running these steps slow down the performance. How can i achieve performance and optimize it with spark api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are many different ways of writing this, but assuming I have understood your example correctly, the spark code below will do the trick. Note that I have added an some extra data to the sample you gave and also that I assume that employee John should have the same id. So my test input looks like this:

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate
val df = sc.parallelize(List((1, "John", new LocalDate(2015,4,14), "C11"),(2, "Roy", new LocalDate(2011,5,20), "C11"),(1, "John", new LocalDate(2010,5,20), "C11"),(1, "John", new LocalDate(2012,5,20), "C10"),(1, "John", new LocalDate(2013,1,14), "C11")))
```

Then for the actual identification of employees that have had the same `code` for at least 2 years:

```
df.map{case (id: Int, name: String, date: LocalDate, code: String) => ((id, name), List((date, code)))}
  .reduceByKey(_++_)
  .filter{case(_, listOfCodes) => listOfCodes.length >= 2} // Not interested in employees with only one code registered
  .flatMapValues(list => {
    def sameCodeForTwoYears(list: List[(LocalDate, String)]): List[(LocalDate, String)]  = {
      list match {
        case x :: Nil => List.empty
        case x :: xs => if (xs.head._1.minusYears(2).isAfter(x._1) && x._2 == xs.head._2) {
          List(x, xs.head)
        } else sameCodeForTwoYears(xs)
        case Nil => List.empty
      }
    }
    sameCodeForTwoYears(list.sortWith((left, right) => left._1.isBefore(right._1)))})
  .map{case((id, name),(date, code)) => (id, name, date, code)}
```

This will output:

```
(1,John,2013-01-14,C11)                                                         
(1,John,2015-04-14,C11)
```

Is this what you were looking for??

I have no idea what sort of performance you will get on your dataset, but hopefully you will get a general idea of how this can be written in Spark.

Comment: thanx. You have guided me to right way.  Now we have RDD[(Int, String, LocalDate, String)] and we map it through case class if i have RDD[Row] then how can i map it. I know it is very basic but i am new to it.

Comment: Glad to help. If the answer was what you were looking for, could you please accept it. That way, I get credit for helping and the question will disappear from the list of "unanswered questions" :-)